# Jersey 2.9 and Jackson provider

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jackson

I'm using Jersey 2.9 along with Jackson, here you can find the dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

I have some POJO classes like Student.class which contains some properties, when I'm executing this client code:

```
Student studentRequest = new Student(); 

Response response = target()
                .path("/students/register")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .post(Entity.json(studentRequest), Response.class);
```

The code does not work and I got this exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase._configForWriting(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter;[Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/cfg/EndpointConfigBase;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:655)
    ...
    at 
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase._configForWriting(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter;[Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/cfg/EndpointConfigBase;
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase._configForWriting(ProviderBase.java:469)
...
```

Anyone got an idea why I get this stacktrace ?

Thank you !

Comment: Make sure you don't have two different versions of the Jackson library in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Encountering the same issue, in my case it helped to fix the java.lang.AbstractMethodError by adding the implementations as dependencies by maven dependency management system to client side in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```